# How to use a class from a module immediately after installing it with Puppet?

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile

I am experimenting with Puppet using Vagrant.  I'm new to Puppet.

I'm installing modules in my Puppet manifest using the approach suggested at: [Can I install puppet modules through puppet manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774980/can-i-install-puppet-modules-through-puppet-manifest)

My default.pp contains something like:

```
$dsesterojava = 'dsestero-java'
exec { 'dsestero-java':
   command => "puppet module install ${dsesterojava}",
   unless  => "puppet module list | grep ${dsesterojava}",
   path    => ['/usr/bin', '/bin']
}

include java::java_7
```

I'm trying to import a module and then immediately use the classes defined in it.

Currently, I get:

```
Error: Could not find class java::java_7
```

If I comment out the include line and re-run it.  The module installs. If I then removed the comment and run the provisioning again then it works.

There is some kind of "*chicken and egg*" situation here.  Can I use a module in the same Puppet manifest that installs it?

How should I solve it?

Comment: No, you cannot do this. When your catalog is compiled, Puppet will search for all of the required code and data. Since the `java` module does not exist until catalog application, the compilation of a catalog depending upon it will fail. You are absolutely dealing with a "chicken and egg" situation here. I highly recommend against using Puppet code to install Puppet code.

Comment: Additionally, the link you provided does not suggest this approach, but rather to use librarian-puppet. That (or its successors r10k and code-manager) are highly recommended over this approach.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard.  I'm just learning Puppet but we have Puppet Enterprise locally, which I have just discovered uses r10k - so I shall give that a go.

Comment: Installing Puppet modules for use within Vagrant is also kind of a different beast entirely when you are using them with the internal Puppet provisioner for Vagrant. I expect sooner or later Frederic Henri will arrive and explain the best way to do this, as whenever I Puppet+Vagrant I am doing it for testing purposes and therefore never have to deal with this. Also, if you have Puppet Enterprise you can use "r10k++" (Code Manager), but this would be for the agent provisioner and not the apply provisioner.

Comment: You really should mark @MattSchuchard's first answer as correct, as this code would never work. I think the poster may be looking for a masterless Puppet set-up, which is why he was looking into librarian-puppet.

Comment: I don't think you can mark a comment as an answer - I would if I could

Comment: Well then, upon request I have converted and expanded the comments into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. When your catalog is compiled, Puppet will search in the appropriate directories for all of the required code and data. Since the `java` module does not exist until catalog application, the compilation of a catalog (occurs prior to application) depending upon it will fail. You are absolutely dealing with a "chicken and egg" situation here. I highly recommend against using Puppet code to install Puppet code.

Alternatively, the recommended approach to install and manage your Puppet modules is to use one of these solutions:

- librarian-puppet: http://librarian-puppet.com/
- r10k: https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k
- code-manager (PE only): https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.3/code_management/code_mgr.html

These will also solve the problem for you within the Vagrant if you are using the `agent` provisioner and subscribing the Vagrant instance to a Puppet Master.

If you are using the `apply` provisioner inside of Vagrant, then you will need to go a different route. The simplest solution is to use the `shell` provisioner to install Puppet modules via `module install` after the Puppet installation (unless you are using a Vagrant box with Puppet baked in, in which case you are probably not installing Puppet on it). Alternatively, you could share a directory with the host where your modules are installed, or install the `librarian-puppet` or `r10k` gems onto the Vagrant box and then use them to install into the appropriate path. I can go into more detail on these upon request.

Comment: Worth mentioning here https://github.com/xorpaul/g10k, a lightning fast r10k replacement in Go. I made the switch and won't look back.

Comment: @AlexHarvey as much as I loathe developing in go, I have already seen the performance comp between Goss and Serverspec so I can guess something similar is happening here. I need to find out if Puppet knows about this and wants to internalize it, or at least make this a swappable backend for r10k with Code Manager; either would allow me to pitch it to Enterprise organizations. Anyway, great find there.

Comment: Well I told them about it on the Puppet Community Slack and a few people seemed impressed. They ought to internalize it.